# How do you customize the the profile photo in 8.2 or newer?

Tags: content-editor

From the desktop I've only been able to change the background to one of the predefined images; same goes for the profile. Not finding any articles that relate specifically to those images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that you have a few options.

The first option is to open up the *Portraits.config** and modify the list of *pipe-delimited* icons.

The second option I discovered is you can simply paste in a new url in the user manager. As seen below, I pasted in a public image url and it showed up upon refresh of the screen.

[image: Public image url]

If using Sitecore PowerShell Extensions, you can update the profile portrait and desktop with the following script. Adapt to C# if you want to perform this in your own module. Looks like the wallpaper requires a local path.

```
$user = Get-User -Current
$user.Profile.Portrait = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/562466745340817408/_nIu8KHX.jpeg"
$user.Profile.SetCustomProperty("Wallpaper", "/sitecore/shell/themes/backgrounds/Field.jpg")
$user.Profile.Save()
```

The third option may be as Owen described.

Answer (score 1):

The backgrounds are taken from:
\Website\sitecore\shell\Themes\Backgrounds
You can drop an image in there and then you'll be able to select it in the Sitecore desktop. I don't know if there's a better way to get the image in to that folder be I coudn't see one.

Looking at the profile images now - will edit if I find anything :)

EDIT: It *looks* like this is coming from the Office.zip icons but I can't find how they're selected. I'll have another look later.